# Как в С реализовать функцию которая устанавливает в 0 заданное количество бит?

Tags: c, функции

Подскажите каким образом в С можно реализовать функцию которая принимает на вход `void` указатель, и длину `size_t`

```
void zerobyte(void *p, size_t n)
```

программа должна работать по следующему принципу

```
void main()
{
    int p = 3; //00000011
    zerobyte(&p, 1);//p должен стать 2
    p = 3;
    zerobyte(&p, 2);//а тут p должен стать 0
 }
```

проблема в том что я максимум смог найти как обнулить только первый бит

```
void zerobyte(void *p, size_t n)
{
    p &= ~0x01;
}
```

И ума не приложу как это можно сделать.
Каким образом можно реализовать эту функцию?

Comment: При `p=9;//1001` чему должно быть равно значение функции? `zerobyte(&p, 2)` = 8 или 0`?

Comment: должна стать 8 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void zerobyte(void *p, size_t n){

    n= (1<<n) - 1; //преобразует n из 10(n раз)B в 1(n раз)B
    *p &= ~n; //создаёт маску из всех установленных бит, кроме n младших бит

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```
void zerobits(void *p, size_t n)
{
    size_t bytes = n / CHAR_BIT;
    memset(p, 0, bytes);
    ((unsigned char *)p)[bytes] &= (unsigned char)(0xff << (n % CHAR_BIT));
}
```